# Excplicit conversion from object to Outlook.AppointmentItem or Outlook.MailItem (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, outlook, type-conversion, uipath

I need to send an Outlook appointment using UiPath studio. I've got a VB code creating appointment, but UiPath is not a great IDE unfortunatelly.

My code looks like this:

```
 Dim app As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application = New
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application

 Dim tmpapp As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem =
 app.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olAppointmentItem)

 tmpapp.Subject = "Testing Appointment" 

 tmpapp.Body = "Siema siema"

 tmpapp.Location = "tutej" 

 tmpapp.Start = Convert.ToDateTime("10.06.2019 23:33:12") 

 tmpapp.End = Convert.ToDateTime("10.06.2019 23:35:13") 

 tmpapp.ReminderSet = True

 tmpapp.ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = 10
```

But i receive a compiling error:

> Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from ‘Object’ to ‘Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AppointmentItem’.

At line 3

As much as I would like to, I cannot set `Option Strict Off`. It is just not possible.

Do you know how can I convert it explicitly?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you know what a cast is?  If not, you should learn now.  That `CreateItem` method apparently returns an `Object` reference, presumably because it can create items of multiple types.  If the actual object is a specific type and you want to use it as that specific type then you need to cast it as that type.

Comment: You should get over that desire to turn `Option Strict Off`.  It should be `On` at all times other than when turning it `Off` is essential.  Even then, you should work out the smallest amount of code that requires it and move that to one or more partial classes and turn it `Off` only in those code files, leaving it `On` by default for the rest of the project.

Comment: Use DirectCast().

Comment: Yeah, DirectCast worked great. Thanks to both of you for guidance.